# Possibility of DND 5e AC buld-up

Tags: dnd-5e, armor-class

I read in the DND 5e player's handbook about AC and I'm confused if my build is ok or not.

I'm trying to create lvl 4 character with a lot of AC with a light armor.

So here it is: A Tabaxi, Fighter Eldritch Knight with Defense archetype.

My Dex add +3 AC  /  I use a shield +2 AC  /  Wear a studded leather +12 AC  /  Defense Archetype +1 AC / Get the feat Defensive duelist + 2 AC (in reaction) / And maybe use the spell Shield.

So is there anything that I cannot mix together or use at same time?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to remember that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game and edition you're asking about?

Comment: Was this [your original question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167725/ac-calulation-with-a-defense-figther-shield-defensive-duelist)? Totally okay if it is, but if so it's better to edit than to create a new account.

Comment: There have been several editions of D&D, each with very different, and incompatible, rulesets. Can you tell us which edition you're asking about?

Comment: thank you everyone. Sorry to make you repeat the same thing all over again. Aslo how can I erase the other post?

Comment: It looks like we've decided to move forward using your original post. There's nothing to worry about really, this'll get clean out automatically in a few days. Though in general, if you complete registration (there should be a banner up top) you can delete your own posts (unless answered) and you may well want to do that anyway so you can be sure you can log back into it (and not trust on your cookies).